# (SQLite) Count number of times a value repeats 3 times continuously

Tags: sql, sqlite

I understand that this is a complex query, thus I have a separate column for this, but the column contains almost 99% values as null (which is very ineffecient), thus I want to know it its possible to do this through a query.

I have table something like this:

```
TransactionId | Value | ProductId
      1           3         2
      2           2         2           
      3           1         2
      4           0         4
      5           0         4
      6           0         4
      7           3         7
      8           3         7
      9           1         7
     10           0         3
     11           0         3
     12           0         3
     13           5         1
     14           2         1
     15           3         1
     16           0         4
     17           0         4
     18           0         4
```

Now the query is, that if for 3 **consecutive** product ids, the corresponding value is 0 (in order of TransactionId ASC), then it will be counted as 1 for `ProductId` i.e.

```
ProductId | Count 
    4         2
    3         1
```

**How can we query this?**

An optional short question :p

Is it alright if I have columns which have mostly null values?

Comment: What happens if you have four adjacent rows that are 0?  Seven?

Comment: It can never happen that the value column has 4 adjacent 0s and the corresponding productid is same

Comment: Post sample data including nulls and explain what happens in case where there is for example 0,null,0,0,null for a productid. Also by `consecutive product ids` you mean consecutive ordered by TransactionId, right?

Comment: Yes `consective product ids` ordered by `Transactionid`. Also, null and 0 mean the same thing in my database. So even if it is `0, null, 0` consecutively for a `productid` it should be counted as 1 for corresponding `productid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the more recent versions of SQLite, you can use `lag()`/`lead()`:

```
select product_id, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (case when value = 0 and
                        lead(value, 1) over (partition by productid order by transactionid) = 0 and
                        lead(value, 2) over (partition by productid order by transactionid) = 0
                   then 1
              end) as three_zero_flag
      from t
     ) t
where three_zero_flag = 1
group by product_id
```

Comment: If you don't mind can you explain me how does lag/lead work here?

Comment: `Lag()` function... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
`Lead()` function... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
Think of Lag as lagging behind. So for the current row, the `lag()` will look at the previous row and the `lead()` will look at the next subsequent (ahead) row.

Comment: Maybe better check the SQLite documentation https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#built_in_window_functions rather than Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out here! :) I think this will work just fine. When I reach home I'll check if it works fine on my main database and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First use a CTE to get the rows with 3 consecutive 0s and then include from them only 1 (so only 1 will be counted) in the table:

```
with 
cte as (
  select * from (
    select *,
      lag(transactionid) over (order by transactionid) previd,
      lead(transactionid) over (order by transactionid) nextid,
      lag(productid) over (order by transactionid) prevprodid,
      lead(productid) over (order by transactionid) nextprodid,
      lag(value) over (order by transactionid) prevvalue,
      lead(value) over (order by transactionid) nextvalue
    from tablename
  ) t
  where 
    productid = prevprodid and productid = nextprodid and 
    coalesce(value, 0) = 0 and  coalesce(prevvalue, 0) = 0 and coalesce(nextvalue, 0) = 0
),
triples as (select previd id from cte union all select nextid from cte)

select productid, count(*) counter 
from tablename 
where transactionid not in (select id from triples)
group by productid
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/65NhtLCNNTEGnRExxZoFU2/1).
Results:

```
| ProductId | counter |
| --------- | ------- |
| 1         | 3       |
| 2         | 3       |
| 3         | 1       |
| 4         | 2       |
| 7         | 3       |
```